# Android Studio does not have Java language

Tags: java, android

Friends, when I want to create an empty project in Android Studio, why is the language not Java?
[this is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woe99.jpg)

i want to add java lang in android studio empty project
but i cant
I will do this to reach 200 characters...

Comment: share the dropdown View of Language.

Comment: That's the *build configuration* language, not the language for the code you'll be writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build configuration language is not related to the program code language.

The build configuration is handled by gradle and gradle scripts used to be written in `Groovy`. This is now beeing phased out in favor of a Kotlin based DSL.

So selecting the Kotlin DSL for the build configuration will still allow you to use Java for your actual app.